# Kafka File Sink Connector - output JSON

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

anyone have issues with File Sink Connector output format ?

I wonder why do I receive this kind of format

````
{op=u, before={withTax=1, unit=pc(s), deleted=0, updated_at=null, price=420000.0, name=Test 123, created_at=null, id=54, useTaxIncludedFormula=0}, after={withTax=1, unit=pc(s), deleted=0, updated_at=null, price=333.0, name=Test 123, created_at=null, id=54, useTaxIncludedFormula=0}, source={ts_sec=1561038448, query=null, thread=29638, server_id=100596, version=0.9.5.Final, file=mysql-bin.000012, connector=mysql, pos=1044011265, name=crm-kafka-connector, gtid=null, row=0, snapshot=false, db=gxapp_customer_db, table=registrationItemsTmp}, ts_ms=1561063703793}```
````

but when I view it using kafka-console-consumer.sh i get valid JSON

````
{"before":{"id":54,"name":"Test 123","price":420000.0,"unit":"pc(s)","withTax":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"useTaxIncludedFormula":0,"deleted":0},"after":{"id":54,"name":"Test 123","price":333.0,"unit":"pc(s)","withTax":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"useTaxIncludedFormula":0,"deleted":0},"source":{"version":"0.9.5.Final","connector":"mysql","name":"crm-kafka-connector","server_id":100596,"ts_sec":1561038448,"gtid":null,"file":"mysql-bin.000012","pos":1044011265,"row":0,"snapshot":false,"thread":29638,"db":"gxapp_customer_db","table":"registrationItemsTmp","query":null},"op":"u","ts_ms":1561063703793}```
````

I have setting everything to use JsonConverter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FileStreamSinkConnector will write the data based on the values it receives. The JSONConverter just tells Kafka Connect how to deserialise the messages that it receives.

If you have JSON on the topic that you want to just dump to file then in your sink connector use

```
"value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
```

This link might provide more background that you find useful: [https://rmoff.net/2019/05/08/when-a-kafka-connect-converter-is-not-a-*converter*/](https://rmoff.net/2019/05/08/when-a-kafka-connect-converter-is-not-a-_converter_/)

Comment: Thank you Robin! This solved it! Everything is working properly now.